# How is the total calculated for influenza vaccination coverage calculated?

Tags: vaccination, influenza

I found [these data](http://www.salute.gov.it/portale/documentazione/p6_2_8_3_1.jsp?lingua=italiano&id=19) concerning influenza vaccination coverage in Italy.
I don't understand how the total is calculated. It is not a simple media.

For example, for the season 2016-2017 the data are as follows:

[image]

If I sum up the values of the first line (in red) and average it, I get:

0.5+0.6+0.7+0.8+0.8+1.6+6.4+48.2=59.6/8=7.45 that is different from 14.6.

If instead I sum up the values of the column (in blue) I get:

0.5+0.5+0.6+0.7+2+1.2+0.3+0.9+1.3+5.2+0.3+0.9+0.5+0.6+0.8+2.4+4+0.2+0.6+1.3+1.1=25.9/21=1.23 that is different from 1.5.

So, what kind of calculations were made to get the Total values?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, marielle! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. If you want to improve your question with an [edit], familiarise yourself with [ask]. This message does not judge the quality of your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## These appear to be weighted totals

I don't have the methodology used to to derive these figures, but I would expect that the totals are weighted by age group size (for the last column) and by region population (for the final row).

I used the values for [Italian age distribution](https://www.statista.com/statistics/270473/age-distribution-in-italy/) (NB only goes to 2016, not 2017), and got values closer to the expected values, eg `9.6` for Provincia Bolzano once weighting for age was taken into account.